# ¿Se puede cambiar de cuenta conservando los puntos?

Tags: soporte

El tema es que la cuenta con la que entro en SOes es la de facebook de la empresa donde trabajo por ahora, pero me marcharé de la empresa. 
Quisiera saber si puedo reconfigurar de alguna forma la cuenta para que pueda seguir usandola sin que esté configurada y conectada con el facebook de la empresa. O sea que pueda entrar desde mi casa sin que por ello mi cuenta de SOes tenga nada que ver con la empresa.

Y así seguir teniendo mis puntos y mi nombre.

¿Se entiende la pregunta, se puede hacer?

Comment: En tu perfil puedes añadir distintos _inicios de sesión_, por ejemplo para entrar con gmail en lugar de facebook. ¿Eso te serviría?

Comment: Un caso interesante. Es cierto que ambas preguntas tienen la misma respuesta. Pero las preguntas son fundamentalmente diferentes, el objetivo que se persigue es diferente. Por lo que yo mas bien voto para mantener abierta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Si, es posible añadir un inicio de sesión diferente y también eliminarlos. Debes seguir estos pasos:

1. Pulsa en el menú superior sobre tu perfil:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

2. Después, ve a la pestaña *Edición de perfil y configuración*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

3. En el menú de la parte izquierda, tienes la opción *Mis inicios de Sesión*:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

4. En esta pantalla ya puedes añadir y quitar inicios de sesión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh arreglado!